# Delay in restarting Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app where this is my **main.py**

```
from king_slayer.database import init_db, manager
from king_slayer.views import fetch_production
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    manager.run()
```

Before the `manger.run()` gets executed I want to call

```
fetch_production()
```

so I did this.

```
from king_slayer.database import init_db, manager
from king_slayer.views import fetch_production

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    with manager.app.test_request_context():
        fetch_production()
    manager.run()
```

It works.
The problem is when I kill the `Flask` app and then restart it, It wont startup for like 60-120 seconds. No errors, Nothing. The browser wont load anything. simple 'Problem loading page' appears and after sometime it works fine unless I again restart the `Flask` app.

If I remove

```
with manager.app.test_request_context():
            fetch_production()
```

the delay doesn't happens.

**P.S**
If I dont use `with manager.app.test_request_context():`
Flask throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    fetch_production()
  File "/home/jarvis/Development/kingslayer/king_slayer/king_slayer/views.py", line 156, in fetch_production
    results={"msg": "Database Updated", }
  File "/home/jarvis/Development/kingslayer/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 235, in jsonify
    and not request.is_xhr:
  File "/home/jarvis/Development/kingslayer/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/jarvis/Development/kingslayer/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/jarvis/Development/kingslayer/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

What is happening ?

**P.P.S** `fetch_production()` does something like this

```
requests.get(config.SERVER, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.AUTH_USER, config.AUTH_PASSWORD))
```

makes a few function calls, functions that are defined in `views.py` and then creates an `.ini` file in the file system. Then in the end returns a `return jsonify`.

```
  requests.get(config.SERVER, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(config.AUTH_USER, config.AUTH_PASSWORD))
```

is actually very fast and if the `fetch_production()` is called manually it doesn't take more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: What does fetch_production() do?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what `fetch_production()` does I *guess* that it's  some sort of blocking action that then prevents the subsequent
 call to  `init_db()` once you try to restart the application.

Comment: The Flask [development server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.run) (which calls [`werkzeug.serving.run_simple`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple)) is single threaded by default. When you try to make a request using `requests` to an endpoint served by your application within the context of another request, the server can't process the inner request until the outer one is complete, so it ends up deadlocked.